# Tikz not installed? Yes it is!

Tags: tikz-pgf, mdframed

I am trying to run some `R` markdown code, knitting some LaTeX together, and I am getting these odd warnings:

> Package mdframed Warning: The file tikz does not exist
> (mdframed)                but needed by mdframed
>
> (mdframed)                see documentation fo further information  on input line 382.
>
> (c:/Users/14506498/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mdframed/md-frame-1.mdf
>
> File: md-frame-1.mdf 2013/07/01\ 1.9b: md-frame-1
>
> ! Undefined control sequence.
>
> l.174 \tikzset
> {mdfframetitlerule/.style={%
> ...

However, I have installed `tikz`. Here are the packages my header imports:

- \usepackage{subfig}
- \usepackage{framed}
- \usepackage{adjustbox}
- \usepackage{xcolor}
- \usepackage{booktabs}
- \usepackage{longtable}
- \usepackage{array}
- \usepackage{multirow}
- \usepackage{wrapfig}
- \usepackage{float}
- \usepackage{colortbl}
- \usepackage{pdflscape}
- \usepackage{tabu}
- \usepackage{threeparttable}
- \usepackage{threeparttablex}
- \usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
- \usepackage{makecell}
- \usepackage{tikz}

I have read [elsewhere](https://github.com/brentthorne/posterdown/issues/5) that `xcolor` and `tikz` can sometimes have installation order/compatibility issues. I have tried reinstalling `pgf` and `xcolor` in different orders, but the same error persists. What is the problem?

Comment: quite possibly you have two tex systems, a minimal one for R and a full one with tikz, please show a small complete test file and a full log with the error, as code blocks (`{}` in the editor)  not quotations or itemized lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@DavidCarlisle was correct. MikTeX was installed containing all required packages, but TinyTeX had also been installed, and Rmarkdown was choosing the latter. Errors pointed to `\tikz`/`mdframed` because the first piece of code run called those packages, but in reality TinyTeX may have had none of the packages I needed.

Problem was solved by `tinytex::uninstall_tinytex()`.

I also subsequently ran `remove.packages("tinytex")`. Note the order here is important!).

[Note the distinction](https://yihui.org/tinytex/#for-r-users) between `tinytex` and `TinyTeX`: `TinyTeX` is a LaTeX installation (just like MikTeX, ...) which can be run without R, whereas `tinytex` is an R package which provides easy use/installation/package management of `TinyTeX`.